# hash functions and unconditional security

Tags: encryption, hash, signature

To the extent of my knowledge, hash functions are based on computational complexity (and not on physical laws of quantum mechanics). So they can not provide unconditional security.

But, are there hash functions which provide unconditional security?

Are there quantum hash function which provide unconditional security?

Comment: It is properties like collision resistance or pre-image resistance that can be achieved under computational assumptions. Weaker properties like $k$-wise independence *can* be guaranteed unconditionally.